# nodejs express mongo update array value by where

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a schema in which value have array I need to update the value where value exists

My schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const matchschema = new mongoose.Schema({

    overs: [
        {
            overNumber: {
                type: Number,
            },
            totalRuns: {
                type: Number,
            },
            balls: [
                {
                    ballNumber: {
                        type: Number,
                    },
                    runs: {
                        type: Number,
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    ],

})

exports.Match = mongoose.model('matches', matchschema);
exports.matchschema = matchschema;
```

I need to insert balls where overNumber is 2. I have created a query but not able to add logic what need to add here.

```
    const matchEnd = await Match.findByIdAndUpdate(data.matchID, {

    }, { new: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const matchEnd = await Match.updateMany({ overNumber: 2 }, {
    $push: { balls: {
        ballNumber: 1,
        runs: 2
    } }
})
```

You can read more on [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating-using-queries) and [MongoDB docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/#update-operators-1)